# Train a Neural Network for state prediction of Lorentz system

Tags: database, matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, ode

I have Simulated the Lorentz dynamical system in MATLAB for different values of initial conditions, as follows:

```
clc;clear;close all;

%{
        LoREntz System Estimation
%}

%% 1. Initialization

Ts = 0.01;
tMax = 8;
t = 0:Ts:tMax;

sigma = 10;
ro = 28;
beta = 8/3;

n = 3;  % Number of States
STD = 30;
CTE = 0.5;
Ics = STD*rand(n,1) - CTE;

%% 2. ODE Function

Lorentz = @(t,x) [sigma*(x(2) - x(1))
                  x(1)*(ro - x(3)) - x(2)
                  x(1)*x(2) - beta*x(3)];


%% 3. Solve The Nonlinear ODE

[~,states] = ode45(@(t,x)Lorentz(t,x), t, Ics);

%% 4. Plot Results

f1 = figure(1);
Name = {'x','y','z'};
j = 0;
Colors = hsv(n);

for i=1:n

    j = j + 1;
    subplot(n,1,i)
    plot(t,states(:,i),'color',Colors(j,:),'LineWidth',2,'DisplayName',Name{i})
    xlabel('Time (S)','InterPreter','Latex')
    legend show
    xlim([min(t) max(t)])

end

%% 5. PLot Trajectories for Different Initial COnditions

f2 = figure(2);
DATA = cell(numel(t),1);
% Inputs = [];
% Targets = [];
nIcs = 100;  % For Test

Inputs = struct;
Targets = struct;

Inputs.Input1 = [];
Inputs.Input2 = [];
Inputs.Input3 = [];

Targets.Target1 = [];
Targets.Target2 = [];
Targets.Target3 = [];

for i=1:nIcs

    Ics = STD*(rand(n,1) - CTE);
    [~,states] = ode45(@(t,x)Lorentz(t,x), t, Ics);

    %% 5. 1. Times Series Data

      Inputs.Input1 = [Inputs.Input1;         states(1:end-1,1)];
      Inputs.Input2 = [Inputs.Input2;         states(1:end-1,2)];
      Inputs.Input3 = [Inputs.Input3;         states(1:end-1,3)];

      Targets.Target1 = [Targets.Target1;     states(2:end,1)];
      Targets.Target2 = [Targets.Target2;     states(2:end,2)];
      Targets.Target3 = [Targets.Target3;     states(2:end,3)];

%     Inputs = [Inputs        states(1:end-1,:)];
%     Targets = [Targets      states(2:end,:)];

    %% 5. 2. Trajectories

    plot3(Ics(1),Ics(2),Ics(3),'o','MarkerFaceColor','r')
    hold on
    plot3(states(:,1),states(:,2),states(:,3))
    hold on
    xlabel('x(t)','InterPreter','Latex')
    ylabel('y(t)','InterPreter','Latex')
    zlabel('z(t)','InterPreter','Latex')

end

movegui(f1,'east')
movegui(f2,'west')

%% 6. Save Data

save('Inputs','Inputs')
save('Targets','Targets')
```

As You can see, I have saved the Input and Output data, which are required for the train of the NN. What I do want to obtain is train the network for prediction of the trajectory of the Lorentz system in terms of many different initial conditions. As a matter of fact, I want to solve the system of nonlinear differential equations of Lorentz for all states. Changing the initial conditions yields different outcomes for system states and trajectories. I have trained the Network as follows:

```
clc;clear;close all;

%{
        Train Trajectories of Lorentz System
%}

%% A. Load Data

load Inputs.mat;
load Targets.mat;

nInputs = length(fieldnames(Inputs));
nTargets = length(fieldnames(Targets));

% Input1 = Inputs.Input1;
% Input2 = Inputs.Input2;
% Input3 = Inputs.Input3;
% 
% Target1 = Targets.Target1;
% Target2 = Targets.Target2;
% Target3 = Targets.Target3;

inputs = [Inputs.Input1         Inputs.Input2               Inputs.Input3];
Inputs = inputs';

targets = [Targets.Target1      Targets.Target2             Targets.Target3];
Targets = targets';    

%% B. Create Incipient Network

HiddenLayerSize = [5 5 5];
net = feedforwardnet(HiddenLayerSize);
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'radbas';
net.layers{3}.transferFcn = 'purelin';

AbsError = 1e-8;
MaxFailure = 20;
MaxEpochs = 500;

net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';
net.trainParam.showCommandLine = true;
net.trainParam.show = 40;
net.trainParam.epochs = MaxEpochs;
net.trainParam.goal = AbsError;
net.trainParam.max_fail = MaxFailure;

%% Train Network

tic
net = train(net,Inputs,Targets);
toc

view(net)
% perform(net)

%% Plot Results
```

On the surface, what I'm trying to do is putting all the states together for all sampling times and for all different initial conditions, to train the network. Is this procedure correct? For example, suppose that the first state is obtained for 800 time samples just for 1 sample of initial conditions. If we want to solve the system of differential equations of Lorentz, the first state will be a matrix of size `800*100`. Furthermore, we need to repeat the same procedures for the other 2 states. Can Neural Network correctly predict the data if I give all the 3 states for all sampling times and for different initial conditions as matrix of `3*80000`, and get the output results? I have done the procedures discussed above and the results are shown in the picture.
[image]

Comment: This is an active research topic that you'd need to ask to the best mathematicians and computer scientist in academia, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: The guy with the simplified thermo-dynamic system is Lorenz, the earlier Lorentz is the source for the magneto-electric kinetic law. You have to go some centuries back to get more fluid spelling, where both variants would be exchangeable. For instance Leibniz did indeed have his name also rendered as Leibnitz or Leibnitius.